# NServiceBus ServiceInsight - Monitor Multiple Error and Audit

Tags: nservicebus, serviceinsight

I have a couple questions regarding ServiceInsight that I was hoping someone could shed some light on.

1. Can I monitor multiple error queues and audit queues?  If so how do I configure it to monitor those queues.
2. I understand that messages processed in the error queue are moved to the error.log queue.  What happens to the messages processed in the audit queue, i.e where do they go after the management service processes them.
3. Where are the messages ultimately stored by the management process, i.e. are they stored in RavenDB and if so under what database.
4. In addition, how do I remove or delete message conversations in the endpoint explorer.  For example, let’s say I just want to clear everything out.

Any additional insight (no pun intended) you can provide regarding the management and use of insight would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Question:  Can I monitor multiple error queues and audit queues? If so how do I configure it to monitor those queues.

Answer: ServiceInsight receives its data from a management service (AKA "ServiceControl") that collects its data from audit (and error) queues. A single instance of ServiceControl can connect to a single audit and error queues (in a single transport type). If you install multiple ServiceControl instances that collect auditing and error data form multiple queues, you can use serviceInsight to connect to each of the ServiceControl instances. Currently (in beta) ServiceInsight supports one connection at a time, but you can easily switch between connection or open multiple instances of ServiceInsight, each connecting to a different ServiceControl instance.

Question: I understand that messages processed in the error queue are moved to the error.log queue. What happens to the messages processed in the audit queue, i.e where do they go after the management service processes them.

Answer: audit messages are consumed, processed and stored in the ServiceControl instance auditing database (RavenDB).

Question: Where are the messages ultimately stored by the management process, i.e. are they stored in RavenDB and if so under what database.

Answer: Yes, they are stored (by default) in the embedded RavenDB database that is used by the management service (AKA "ServiceControl"). You can locate it under "C:\ProgramData\Particular\ServiceBus.Management"

Question: In addition, how do I remove or delete message conversations in the endpoint explorer. For example, let’s say I just want to clear everything out.

Answer: We will be adding full purge / delete support for this purpose in an upcoming beta update. for immediate purging of old messages, you can use the RavenDB studio based on the path specific above.

Please let me know of these answer your questions and do not hesitate to raise any other questions you may have!

Best regards,

Danny Cohen
Particular Software (NServiceBus Ltd.)